# failed to load the page ,net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: angularjs

GET file:///C:/Users/rameshl/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/www/cordova.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.86.24.1:9081/myHealthButton/loginAuthenticate.action. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a tomcat, path will be relative to your web application. My guess is that you have in your index.html

```
<script scr="C:/Users/rameshl/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/www/cordova.js > ...</script>
```

Change it by :

```
<script scr="cordova.js > ...</script>
```

Considering that index.html is in the same folder than cordova.js, otherwise use either a relative path  or a path from "/www/[path]".

PS : this is not a angular problem.

Comment: i changed still facing same issue in " 5?ionic platform=android:1 ." and though i run it through browser I'm facing same issue.